# Why the program runs endlessly?

Tags: clojure

Why the program runs endlessly?

```
(defn lazycombine
([s] (lazycombine s []))
([s v] (let [a (take 1 s)
             b (drop 1 s)]
            (if (= a :start)
                (lazy-seq (lazycombine b v))
                (if (= a :end)
                    (lazy-seq (cons v (lazycombine b [])))
                    (lazy-seq (lazycombine b (conj v a))))))))

(def w '(:start 1 2 3 :end :start 7 7 :end))

(lazycombine w)
```

I need a function that returns a lazy sequence of elements by taking elements from another sequence of the form [: start 1 2: end: start: 5: end] and combining all the elements between: start and: end into a vector

Comment: You have no termination condition at all, so it's hard to see how this could ever terminate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the termination condition - i.e. what should return when input `s` is empty?

And also the detection of `:start` and `:end` should use `first` instead of `(take 1 s)`.  And you can simplify that with destructuring.

```clj
(defn lazycombine
  ([s] (lazycombine s []))
  ([[a & b :as s] v]
   (if (empty? s)
     v
     (if (= a :start)
       (lazy-seq (lazycombine b v))
       (if (= a :end)
         (lazy-seq (cons v (lazycombine b [])))
         (lazy-seq (lazycombine b (conj v a))))))))


(def w '(:start 1 2 3 :end :start 7 7 :end))

(lazycombine w)
;; => ([1 2 3] [7 7])
```

To reduce cyclomatic complexity a bit, you can use `condp` to replace couple `if`:

```clj
(defn lazycombine
  ([s] (lazycombine s []))
  ([[a & b :as s] v]
   (if (empty? s)
     v
     (lazy-seq
      (condp = a
        :start (lazycombine b v)
        :end   (cons v (lazycombine b []))
        (lazycombine b (conj v a)))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like so, using `take-while`:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(def data
  [:start 1 2 3 :end :start 7 7 :end])

(defn end-tag? [it] (= it :end))
(defn start-tag? [it] (= it :start))

(defn lazy-segments
  [data]
  (when-not (empty? data)
    (let [next-segment   (take-while #(not (end-tag? %)) data)
          data-next      (drop (inc (count next-segment)) data)
          segment-result (vec (remove #(start-tag? %) next-segment))]
      (cons segment-result
        (lazy-seq (lazy-segments data-next))))))

(dotest
  (println "result: " (lazy-segments data)))
```

Running we get:

```
result:  ([1 2 3] [7 7])
```

Note the contract when constructing a sequence recursively using `cons`  (lazy or not).  You must return either the next value in the sequence, or `nil`.  Supplying `nil` to `cons` is the same as supplying an empty sequence:

```
 (cons 5 nil) => (5)
 (cons 5 [])  => (5)
```

So it is convenient to use a `when` form to test the termination condition (instead of using `if` and returning an empty vector when the sequence must end).

Suppose we wrote the `cons` as a simple recursion:

```
  (cons segment-result
    (lazy-segments data-next))
```

This works great and produces the same result.  The only thing the `lazy-seq` part does is to ***delay when the recursive call takes place***.  Because `lazy-seq` is a Clojure built-in (special form), it it is similar to `loop/recur` and does ***not consume the stack*** like ordinary recursion does .  Thus, we can generate millions (or more) values in the lazy sequence without creating a `StackOverflowError` (on my computer, the default maximum stack size is ~4000).  Consider the infinite lazy-sequence of integers beginning at `0`:

```
(defn intrange
  [n]
  (cons n (lazy-seq (intrange (inc n)))))

(dotest
  (time
    (spyx (first (drop 1e6 (intrange 0))))))
```

Dropping the first million integers and taking the next one succeeds and requires only a few milliseconds:

```
(first (drop 1000000.0 (intrange 0))) => 1000000
"Elapsed time: 49.5 msecs"
```